# Frequency dependance of sound wave reflection

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection, frequency, absorption

Why are high frequencies reflected more than low frequencies off an 'acoustically hard' surface such as concrete? I basically understand that the amount of reflection is determined by the impedance ratio between the two mediums (i.e air/concrete). But does that mean that high frequency sound waves have a lower acoustic impedance than low frequencies (hence why high frequencies are reflected and more than low frequencies?).

Answer (score 2):

[First off, much of this answer is based on the amazingly helpful University of New South Wales website on acoustic impedance.](http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/compliance-inertance-impedance.htm) This is a topic I'm very interested in and this is a great opportunity to reduce the complex topic of impedance down for my own learning purposes as well as to provide an answer.

You ask,

> does that mean that high frequency sound waves have a lower acoustic impedance than low frequencies (hence why high frequencies are reflected and more than low frequencies?)

Actually, specific acoustic impedance, $z$, is a property of the *medium*, not of the waves themselves.  
It has both a real part, **resistance** $r(\omega)$ and an imaginary part, **reactance** $x(\omega)$:

$$z(\omega) = r(\omega) + i \space x(\omega)$$

Where $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $2 \pi f$.

---

Reactance has a positive and a negative part:  **compliance (capacative) reactance** $x_C(\omega)$, and **inertive (inductive) reactance** $x_L(\omega)$:

$$x(\omega) = x_L(\omega) - x_C(\omega)$$

Without going into exhaustive detail, I want to point out the relevant fact that inertiance, associated with the density of the medium, *is proportional* to frequency:

$$x_L(\omega) \propto \omega$$

While compliance, associated with the elasticity of the medium, *is inversely proportional* to frequency:

$$x_C(\omega) \propto \frac{1}{\omega}$$

In other words,

- denser media are more likely to impede high-frequency waves
- more elastic media are more likely to impede high-frequency waves

---

In the example of your concrete wall - a dense, inelastic media relative to air - we might expect more of an impedance missmatch (between the two media) for higher-frequency energy than for the lower frequency energy.  This would result in the higher frequency energy being reflected more.